# Need to increases performance of LEFT JOIN ON condition

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm doing a SQL Request that LEFT JOIN 2 tables.
The 1st LEFT JOIN can be null, but my 2nd LEFT JOIN is using the previous table on ON, but as it can be null, I'm also doing an IF on 2nd LEFT JOIN to join ON a 3rd table :

```sql
...
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.s_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.rr_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t4 ON IF(t3.id,t4.id = t3.i_id,t4.s_id = t2.id)
```

Thing is, my request is really slow (~30sec for 60 rows). I need to keep this check and improve a lot performances of this request

**EDIT**

Quick sample data:

t1 :

| id | s_id (link to t2) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

t2 :

| id | other useless data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

t3 :

| id | rr_id (link to t1) | i_id (link to t4) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 3 | 33 |
| 3 | 1 | 11 |

t4 :

| id | s_id (link to t2) |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 33 | 3 |

I need to join t4 ON t3, but if t3.i_id is null, join t4 on t2.id

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen an if in a join - does it work? sample data and desired output would be nice as would an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Yes, of course it's most common to use a simple equality expression, but a join condition can have any scalar expression. More complex expressions are harder to optimize.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yeah, I know it's not common, but my request is kinda harder. But only this part is messing up. Also, I've had some data if it helps

Comment: RDMS does not like "either JOIN to this table or that table".  Redesign the schema.

Comment: @RickJames unfortunately, this will be impossible. It's not a new schema that I'm creating, it's already a fully operational DB schema, and I can't change it for this "little" request. It's just about exporting some data from DB, and improve performances, but I'll try the UNION answer, hoping it'll improve ^^

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code seems you need  a INNER JOIN between  t4 and t3
and merging the result using UNION beeween the same select base on inner join for t4 and t2 for t2 values when t3.i_d an t4.s_id don't match

```
    select .....
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.s_id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.rr_id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t3.i_id
    
    UNION
    select .....
    FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.rr_id = t2.id
    JOIN t2 ON t1.s_id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN ( 
        select t4.s_id id
        from t4 
        left join t3 on t4.id = t3.i_id
        where t3.i_id is null
    ) tt on tt.id = t2.id
```

Comment: I wont be able to test this week I think, but I'll try it asap.
But just to be sure, isn't your 2d SELECT a line to high ? Supposed to be after the UNION, no ?

Comment: @Devinfo_DH   .. answer  updated ..

Comment: Ok, so I've tested it, looks like the idea is not bad, but I got lot of problem of duplicate column in the SELECT, and I need to add lots of alias so it'll make my code more complicated to add full alias for this request. But it looks really good if using less tables and in a smaller request